# Why my blob is broken when I download it?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-blob-storage

So what I am doing is uploading video chunk by chunk with PutBlock. The requester sends me the video divided by 4mb chunks by per request(if the video is 17mb he/she will send 5 requests, to upload 4mb chunk). I am using PutBlock method to "append" blob... When I download this video from blob it is broken... But if the requester sends me only 3mb video it is not broken...
Please help....

```
   public async Task<CloudBlockBlob> AppendBlobOnAssetAsync(UploadRequest request)
    {
        using Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        request.File.CopyTo(stream);
        stream.Position = 0;

        var cloudBlobContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(request.InputAssetStorageUri);
        var blockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(request.BlobName);

        var blockItems = new List<ListBlockItem>();
        var blockItemIds = new List<string>();

        if (request.BlockId > 0)
        {
            var blocks = await blockBlob.DownloadBlockListAsync();
            blockItems = blocks.ToList();
            blockItemIds = blockItems.Select(blockItem => blockItem.Name).ToList();
        }

        var blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request.BlockId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).PadLeft(30, '0')));

        blockBlob.PutBlock(blockId, stream, null);

        blockItemIds.Add(blockId);
        blockBlob.PutBlockList(blockItemIds);

        return blockBlob;
    }
```

Comment: Just wanted to confirm - request.File - when you construct it locally ? it is not broken ? just want to eliminate the possibility of the missing data at the source

Comment: how should i check that chunks is not broken?

Comment: should i donwload first chunk ?after upload it?

Comment: So I sent 7mb video, when I uploaded 4mb chunk and downloaded it, it was broken too.

Comment: Assuming that you are uploading 7MB file - there are 2 requests. 
You are doing twice of the below : 
request.File.CopyTo(stream);

Is there a way you could dump this locally, and check whether the video is not broken - leaving blob out of the picture

Comment: I am assuming you are having a logic to break a single file outside the mentioned code

Comment: So front end guy just divides it by 4mb chunks, video is not broken...soo look, what happened right now... the video was not broken... I downloaded blob and it was playing and after some time it had not sound....

Comment: So issue is that when front end wants to send 8 mb video(length 3 minutes and 20 second), On first request he sends me 4mb chunk and for experiment reason I save it on folder... when I opened it it was 3 minutes and 20 second video